# Storing data in a map that can be retrieved by N keys

Tags: java

I often have data stored in a Map that I need to retrieve by something other than the Key, so wanted to write a generic class that lets you define up to N keys (with the possibility of each key having a different class). Methods are definied to retrieve both the first matching result, and all matching results.

I achieved this by internally creating an ID which is mapped to the data, and keys which are mapped to a list of their matching IDs. Here's my implementation:

```
public class MultiKeyMap<T> {

private Map<Long, T>                            dataMap = new HashMap<>();
private Map<Class<?>, Map<Object, List<Long>>>  keyMaps = new HashMap<>();
private long                                    id      = 0;

/**
 * Construct a data map with the given data and key function(s)
 * 
 * @param data
 * @param keyFunctions
 */
@SafeVarargs
public MultiKeyMap(Collection<T> data, Function<T, ?>... keyFunctions) {
    addAll(data);
    for (Function<T, ?> f : keyFunctions) {
        addKey(f);
    }
}

/**
 * Add an additional key function to this data map.
 * 
 * @param keyFunction
 * @return
 */
public <K> MultiKeyMap<T> addKey(Function<T, K> keyFunction) {
    if (keyFunction == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Key function must not be null");
    }
    Map<Object, List<Long>> keyMap = new HashMap<>();
    Class<?> keyClass = keyFunction.apply(dataMap.values().iterator().next()).getClass();
    if (keyMaps.containsKey(keyClass)) {
        keyMap = keyMaps.get(keyClass);
    }
    for (Entry<Long, T> e : dataMap.entrySet()) {
        K key = keyFunction.apply(e.getValue());
        if (!keyMap.containsKey(key)) {
            List<Long> l = new ArrayList<>();
            l.add(e.getKey());
            keyMap.put(key, l);
        } else {
            keyMap.get(key).add(e.getKey());
        }
    }
    keyMaps.put(keyClass, keyMap);
    return this;
}

/**
 * Add a single element to this data map
 * 
 * @param data
 */
public void add(T data) {
    if (data == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Data must not be null");
    }
    dataMap.put(id++, data);
}

/**
 * Add a collection to this data map
 * 
 * @param data
 */
public void addAll(Collection<T> data) {
    if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Data must not be empty or null");
    }
    for (T t : data) {
        dataMap.put(id++, t);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns true if there is a mapping for the given key
 * 
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return keyMaps.get(key.getClass()).containsKey(key);
}

/**
 * Get a single result from the given key
 * 
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public T get(Object key) {
    return dataMap.get(keyMaps.get(key.getClass()).get(key).get(0));
}

/**
 * Get a list of results from the given key
 * 
 * @param key
 * @return
 */
public List<T> getAll(Object key) {
    return keyMaps.get(key.getClass()).get(key).stream().map(a -> dataMap.get(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Return the size of the map
 * 
 * @return
 */
public int size() {
    return dataMap.size();
}

/**
 * Returns true if the map is empty
 * 
 * @return
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return dataMap.isEmpty();
}

/**
 * Return true if this map contains the given value
 * 
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    return dataMap.containsValue(value);
}

/**
 * Clear this map of all of its data
 */
public void clear() {
    dataMap = new HashMap<>();
    keyMaps = new HashMap<>();
    id = 0;
}

/**
 * Return a list of all key sets generated for this map
 * 
 * @return
 */
public List<Set<Object>> keySets() {
    return keyMaps.values().stream().map(a -> a.keySet()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

/**
 * Return the key set for the given class
 * 
 * @param keySetClass
 * @return
 */
public Set<Object> keySet(Class<?> keySetClass) {
    return keyMaps.get(keySetClass).keySet();
}

/**
 * Return all values in this map
 * 
 * @return
 */
public Collection<T> values() {
    return dataMap.values();
}

}
```

Internally the class of the key is used to to populate the key map, for a faster retrieval of the data, since almost always the keys that are defined will be of a different class. In the case that they are not, this may produce additional search results, but this is acceptable (for example, if for a Person, a key is defined to be a the firstName (String.class), and a second to be lastName (String.class), when searching for "Smith", all matching first and last names of Smith will be returned, e.g. "John Smith" and "Smith Jones")

Given a Person class as an example:

```
public class Person {
    private String  firstName;
    private String  lastName;
    private String  streetName;
    private int     doorNumber;
}
```

The MultiKeyMap could be initialised like this,

```
MultiKeyMap<Person> map = new MultiKeyMap<>(data, Person::getLastName, Person::getDoorNumber);
```

which would allow for retrieval of the data by their last name, or the door number.

I tested it compared to a traditional nested Map approach, and this seems to run in about the same time or less (comparing only the retrival time as initialisation time is not a problem here).

My questions: Could this code be improved? Are there cases when it may not work?

[EDIT] Added a unit test (based on the same Person class as before) to show how this might be used, and what results are expected below.

```
@Test
public void tester() {
    List<Person> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Person p1 = new Person("John", "Smith", "Street", 6);
    Person p2 = new Person("Smith", "Jones", "Road", 7);
    Person p3 = new Person("Alex", "Brown", "Street", 6);
    Person p4 = new Person("Jane", "Smith", "Road", 8);
    data.add(p1);
    data.add(p2);
    data.add(p3);
    data.add(p4);

    MultiKeyMap<Person> map = new MultiKeyMap<>(data, Person::getDoorNumber, Person::getLastName);
    // get where doorNumber=7
    Assert.assertEquals(p2, map.get(7));

    List<Person> expected = new ArrayList<>();
    expected.add(p1);
    expected.add(p4);
    // get where lastName="Smith"
    Assert.assertEquals(expected, map.getAll("Smith"));
}
```

Comment: expected is the first argument in `assertEquals`

Answer (score 1):

1. I would drop

```
private Map<Long, T>                            dataMap = new HashMap<>();
private long                                    id      = 0;
```

And use directly

```
private Map<Class<?>, Map<Object, List<T>>>  keyMaps = new HashMap<>();
```

You are already storing pointers to objects, you aren't saving any memory with dataMap.

2. I would expect that add() method adds new item also to keyMaps.
3. Why not allow for multiple keys of same type? Maybe change the API to something like:

```
MultiKeyMap<Person> map = new MultiKeyMap<>(data);
Map<String, List<Person>> byLast = map.by(Person::getLastName);
Map<String, List<Person>> byFirst = map.by(Person::getFirstName);
```

On the other hand you could just use built in Streams:

```
List<Person> data;
...
Map<String, List<Person>> byLast = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName));
Map<String, List<Person>> byFirst = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFirstName));
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You're right, I'll scrap the ID and the add function definitely should add the new key - that was an oversight, although this would mean storing the Function passed to the mapping function which I wanted to avoid so might just remove it altogether since I don't really need it.
Thanks for some interesting further exercises to do but it doesn't really fit my use case - although my fault for not explaining what it is!